# Should all Mage the Awakening questions have the 'rapidly evolving' post notice?

Tags: discussion, world-of-darkness, post-notice

The new edition of Mage the Awakening has not been finalized yet, should they have this post notice (if it's available on this stack)?

Here's a [list](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-the-awakening+chronicles-of-darkness-2e) of all such questions (along with some false positives).

Comment: Aren't existing questions about the existing edition, not the unfinished one?

Comment: A few are,  where they list another splat (e.g. [tag:werewolf-the-forsaken]) but recent ones tagged with [tag:chronicles-of-darkness-2e] are. Maybe we need a new tag.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's time for a MtA 2nd edition tag.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't need the Rapidly Changing template message — either the answer is knowable and answers will be submitted, the question will get closed as unclear, or it will just remain unanswered until an answer exists. If later changes to the rules invalidate a particular answer post, then the usual site processes that cope with such things (downvotes, edits, comments, new answers, etc.) should take care of it.

Since this is a new edition, it likely also needs a new tag to isolate its questions from questions about *Mage: the Awakening* 1st edition. A [mage-the-awakening-2e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mage-the-awakening-2e) tag would probably fit the bill.